# Как получить паку в которой лежит prefab?

Tags: c#, unity3d, url, prefabs

У меня есть виджет в EditorWindow который формирует список префабов:

```
public static GameObject[] ObjectArrayField(ArrayFieldSettings settings, GameObject[] array) {
    return ObjectArrayField(settings.label, ref settings.open, array);
}
static public GameObject prefab;
public static GameObject[] ObjectArrayField(string label, ref bool open, GameObject[] array) {

    open = EditorGUILayout.Foldout(open, label);
    int newSize = array.Length < 0 ? 0 : array.Length;
    if (open) {
        newSize = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Size", newSize);
        newSize = newSize < 0 ? 0 : newSize;

        if (newSize != array.Length) {
            array = ResizeArray<GameObject>(array, newSize);
            for(int j=0;j<array.Length;j++) {
                //GameObject prefab;
                array[j] = prefab;
            }
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < newSize; i++) {
            if(array[i]==null) {
                array[i] = (GameObject)EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(i.ToString(),array[i], typeof(GameObject), true);
            } else {
                array[i] = (GameObject)EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(array[i].name,array[i], typeof(GameObject), true);
            }
        }
        // EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(array, new GUIContent("Порядок следования", "обозначь последовательность."), true);

    }

    return array;
}
```

Как потом у назначенных префабов достать ссылки, где лежат эти префабы?
У GameObject, есть только название. Как получить ссылку где лежит префаб я не понял.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если в вашем окне есть ссылка на конкретный gameObject, который инстанциирован из какого-либо префаба, то путь к префабу можно получить так:

```
Object parentObject = PrefabUtility.GetCorrespondingObjectFromSource(obj);
string path = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(parentObject);
```

Если ваши GameObject и есть изначально префабы, то найти их можно вызвав только:

```
string path = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(obj);
```

Comment: Не получилось path= пусто, ещё ругается что EditorUtility.GetPrefabParent устаревший я заменил на PrefabUtility.GetCorrespondingObjectFromSource(GamObjArrayPrefab[i]);, но всё равно  path= пусто

Comment: @IvanTriumphov попробуйте еще Object parentObject = PrefabUtility.GetPrefabParent(obj).

Comment: @IvanTriumphov еще уточните пожалуйста версию Юнити

Comment: Unity 2018.4.1f1 (64-bit)

Comment: PrefabUtility.GetPrefabParent тоже устаревшая и не приводить к получении сслыки

Comment: @IvanTriumphov у вас объекты в списке получаются же не GameObject, а как раз сами по себе префабы? в документации написано, что GetCorrespondingObjectFromSource найдет родителя, из которого объект будет инстанциирован. Попробуйте вызвать только AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100195/discussion-between-ivan-triumphov-and-vmchar).

Comment: оставите только:string path = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(obj);